# ggplot2 : Can't add ` ` to a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, syntax-error

everyone I generated 2 ggplot figures and I would like now to add them into the same figure, to do that I simply add the `+`. So I have 2 plots : (1 ggtree and 1 heatmap)

and I'm trying to add them in the same plot with :

```
ggplot<- gg_tr + gg_heat + plot_annotation(tag_levels="A")
```

But then I get the following issue message:

```
Error : Can't add `gg_heat` to a ggplot object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: maybe you want to use the patchwork package - then `+` will combine plots

Comment: Thank you it workes now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
library(patchwork)
gg_tr + gg_heat
```

Comment: some explanation could be useful

Answer (score 0):

If using `ggpubr::ggarrange()`, you need to put a comma and not a `+`.

```
ggarrange(histo_qmean, histo_gmean, histo_qmed, histo_gmed,
          labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

I got the same error by wrongly using `+`, for anyone looking for it.

Answer (score -2):

Need to add parentheses

```
ggplot<- gg_tr() + gg_heat() + plot_annotation(tag_levels="A")
```

Comment: This just produces error messages that R cannot find the function with the plot name.